# Cross validation on glm model in R using CVtools

Tags: r, glm, cross-validation

So I had a similar problem not too long ago and someone suggested to me to reduce my data set, which I have done so massively. At first I had 1664 variables, and now I only have 153. I'm attempting to plot a general linear model between a dependent variable called Retention time, against 153 descriptors. I have 160 examples of retention time against descriptors, so it's a 160 x 153 dataset. I then want to perform five fold cross validation on the model to see how accurate it is, and to later plot a predicted retention time to experimental retention time plot. I'm using CVtools to do this.

```
> library(cvTools)
> cadets <- read.csv("U:/Final Year/CADETS.csv")
> View(cadets)
> folds <- cvFolds(nrow(cadets), K = 5, R = 10)
> fit <- lm(RT..seconds.~., data=cadets)
> folds <- cvFolds(nrow(cadets), K = 5, R = 10)
> repCV(fit, cost = rtmspe, folds = folds, trim = 0.1)
```

However, I get the message:-

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
1: In predict.lm(...) : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
2: In predict.lm(...) : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
3: In predict.lm(...) : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

and it continues. I read somewhere that it might be due to data being colinear. So I decided to perform PCA if that was the case, only to find that after I plotted my components together, they were all pointing in different directions, which suggests that they weren't colinear.

Can anyone understand what is happening and where I'm going wrong? I've copied and pasted a very small section of the database I'm using. So I'm trying to plot RT (seconds) vs 76_TI2, 114_DECC and all the other 151 descriptors for all 160 cases and perform cross validation on it.

```
RT (seconds)    76_TI2  114_DECC    120_Lop 212_PCD
38  4.086   1.2 2.322   0
40  2.732   0.815   1.837   1.113
41  4.049   1.153   2.117   2.354
41  4.049   1.153   2.117   3.838
42  4.56    1.224   2.128   2.38
42  2.96    0.909   1.686   0.972
42  3.237   0.96    1.922   1.202
44  2.989   0.8 1.761   2.034
44  1.993   0.5 1.5 0
44  2.957   0.8 1.761   0.988
44  2.597   0.889   1.888   1.916
44  2.428   0.691   1.436   1.848
44  4.049   1.153   2.117   2.354
44  3.108   0.826   1.686   1.826
44  2.416   1   0.714   28.876
44  2.395   0.778   1.73    2.532
45  1.28    0.75    1.124   0
45  1.27    0.625   1.124   0
45  2.666   0.833   1.792   0
```

[image: PCA of all the descriptor components]

Comment: Upload the image somewhere, put the link in the comment and I (or someone else) will add it for you.

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/2irrxfm.png
This is the image of my PCA of all my descriptor components, thanks!

Comment: After a PCA all the components area _supposed_ to be orthogonal to each other. It doesn't mean that the original data wasn't collinear.

Comment: Yes, PCA will transform your original 153 variables into a new set of mutually orthogonal variables. Try `cor(RT[,-1])`. This produces a matrix of correlation coefficients between each of your original variables and very other one (excluding the first one, `seconds`.) Then see if any are exactly or nearly = 1.